# check 3 element of matrix 3 x 3 in axes x, y and diagonal if it's equal to each other

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

I want to write a code to check the 3 elements inside a matrix 3 x 3 in the x, y, and diagonal and print success in the output. Can anyone help me

Comment: You fill an matrix and you search 3 value in this matrix if there are exist,This is your question ?

Comment: no, i need to check the elements inside the matrix in axes x, y, and diagonal

Comment: you're writing a function that takes a 3x3 matrix as input, and returns true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question ,I use a booleen function to check if the three value exist in the matrix or no

my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool Exist(int rows,int cols,int matrix[rows][cols],int Val);

int main(void)
{
    int rows=3, cols=3;
    /*
    do
    {
        printf("Give me the number of rows :");
        scanf("%d",&rows);
    }while(rows<1);
    
    do
    {
        printf("Give me the number of cols :");
        scanf("%d",&cols);
    }while(cols<1);
    **/

   int arr[rows][cols];

   printf("\nThe filling of the Matrix :\n");

   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
       {
           scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
       }
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   {printf("\n");
      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
      {
          printf("[%d]",arr[i][j]);
      }
   }

   printf("\n\n");
   int VAL_1=0,VAL_2=0,VAL_3=0;
   printf("\nGive me Value 1 & Value 2 & Value 3 :");
   scanf("%d%d%d",&VAL_1,&VAL_2,&VAL_3);
   if((Exist(rows,cols,arr,VAL_1)==false)||(Exist(rows,cols,arr,VAL_2)==false)||(Exist(rows,cols,arr,VAL_3)==false))
   {
       printf("\nThe three values don't exist in this matrix !\n\n");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("\nThe three values exist in this matrix !\n\n");
   }
   printf("\n\n");
   return 0;
}

bool Exist(int rows,int cols,int matrix[rows][cols],int Val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                if((matrix[i][j]==Val)||(matrix[j][i]==Val))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
       if(matrix[i][i]==Val)
       {
          return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```